# Azure Event hub across the regions

Tags: azure-eventhub

Can someone help,

1) We have a scenario where we do have one Eventhub(Eh1) in one region X and can we use the same Eventhub(Eh1) across the different regions at a time or at least in case of Disaster recovery process.

In detail

We have a server running in Primary Region(Server Primone) & a similar replicative Secondary server(Server Secone) running in Secondary Region. We have a mobile device with which we will be sending messages to the server (Primone) in the Primary Region via event hub (Eh1).Can i use the same event hub(Eh1) in case my server(Primone) in the primary region goes down & not accessible?

Suggestions might be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The event hub does not care about the region. If the primary server goes down, then you can configure event hub to send to the secondary-server.

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Comment: Are you suggesting DR scenario?

Comment: @ThayyurKumar, what is DR scenario?